# Different arrangement of books (Permutation)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**There are 5 math books, 3 english books, and 2 physics book.**

1. How many different arrangements were there if the books are different from each other and the books of the same subject must be placed side by side?
2. In how many ways can the student assistant arrange the books on the shelf if books of the same subject are indistinguishable from each other?
3. In how many ways can the student assistant arrange the books on the shelf if books of the same subject are indistinguishable from each other and must be placed side by side?

*I am confused with the three questions. I am not sure what is the difference of the three questions. With the first question, I did this **5!×3!×2!**, but I am not sure if this is right. Please help me and thank you in advance.*

Comment: The difference between the questions is in the word _"indistinguishable"_; the first question assumes the books are all different, the second and third assumes books of the same subject are identical, with the second question not requiring that the books of the same subject be placed together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) and 3), keep in mind that there are $3!$ ways in arrange the string MEP

for 2) you need the number of 10 character strings containing 5 M's, 3 E's and 2 P's
$$N = \frac{10!}{5!3!2!}$$